# Open Outlook from code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am trying to open outlook from code behind but everything works fine for me when i run it from my local machine but i am getting an error when i deployed to the server. I am getting this error:

```
"404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is so far. I need to use onrow command event so i can send a different email based on the command button that the user is selected. I just need the outlook to open and i am assigning programmatically the subject and body content and even the mailto.
here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
                CellPadding="4" PageSize="200" OnRowCommand="GridViews_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging_gvDetail"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" EnableViewState="True">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F3F3F3" />
                <Columns>


                  <asp:BoundField DataField="contract_name" HeaderText="Category" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="vendor_name" HeaderText="Vendor Name" />


                  <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Reconciliation of Spend Metrics" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/img/mail.png"  ControlStyle-Width="30px" ControlStyle-Height="30px" CommandName="Select" />
                  <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Request Call/Meeting with Supplier" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/img/mail.png" ControlStyle-Width="30px" ControlStyle-Height="30px" CommandName="Select1" />

                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollHeader" BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollItem" ForeColor="#000066" />
              </asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
 protected void GridViews_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ToString());


      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);


        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {

          int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          string contractname = gvDetail.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
          string vendorname = gvDetail.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;

           oMsg.Subject = "test";
          oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
          oMsg.HTMLBody = "<p> "test..." + Environment.NewLine + "</p>"; //Here comes your body;

          oMsg.Display(false); //In order to display it in modal inspector change the argument to true
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the directory path that it cant find?

Comment: i am not sure, but that is the error i am getting..

Comment: Does the server *have* Outlook installed? Have you considered just using `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient`?

Comment: yes it has outlook installed.  I don't want to send the email right away, i just want to open the outlook first and let the user send.

Comment: Do you want the server admin to find all these copies of Outlook running with emails to send, or are you expecting the user of the web site to have outlook (or their preferred mail client) open with an email to send? If the later, then you need to use a link with the `mailto:` scheme - which will open a mail client on the users machine if they have one.

Comment: Using Interop over web applications is not a good option. @moe

Answer (score 2):

Your code would be running on the server where there is no interactive user to access Outlook. Worse than that, Outlook cannot be used from a service (such as IIS).

Create an EML file and provide a link to your website user - Outlook (on the client side) will be happy to open and display it.